# Ajax and Browser history using YUI Browser History Class

Tags: cross-browser, extjs, yui, browser-history

I have an Ajax rich application that displays a grid with 100 urls. When u click on any row of the grid it loads the preview of that URL in the grid. 
Also on the onload event of the grid I perform several operation which fire many AJAX queries.

I use YUI browser history class to enable browser back button. It works fine with FF3 but in Safari the whole page seems to be reloading "sometimes". 
Also in IE the browser back inteferes with my iframe.

Also if I copy paste the URL I dont get the expected state. i.e. the one defined in #token

Are these known issues or am I making a mistake?

Is it a good idea to enable browser back for operations when many state changes are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the ability, I would switch to using Ext 2.2's new History object instead of the YUI. I think you might get better cross browser support.

As much of a hassle as it might be, I would definitely consider state management important, to avoid issues with users utilizing the back button.

Comment: I have tried that as well. But no avail.
As far as implementation is concerned I dont see much difference in YUI and Ext.History singleton